# Is there anyway to make this numpy array operation faster?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a matrix:

```
A = [[2, 1]
     [1, 2]]
```

And a list of matrices:

```
B = [[1, 0]   C = [[2, 1],  D = [[0, 0],  E = [[1, 0],
     [1, 0]]       [0, 0]]       [0, 0]]       [0, 0]]
```

I first wish to flatten `A.flatten() = [2 1 1 2]` Then get the sum of these elements multiplied with `B`, `C`, `D` and `E` respectively. So:

```
A[0] * B + A[1]*C + A[2]*D + A[3]*E
```

Now consider a more general case:

```
A[0] * X_1 + A[1] * X_2 + ... + A[n-1] * X_n
```

Where `X_n` can have any dimension. This is the code I have come up with to do this:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul

def product(iterable):
    return reduce(mul, iterable)


def create_table(old_shape, new_shape):
    # Create X_1, X_2, ..., X_n
    lookup = []
    for _ in range(product(old_shape)):
        lookup.append(np.random.rand(*new_shape))
    return lookup


def sum_expansion(arr, lookup, shape):
    # A[0] * X_1 + ... + A[n-1] * X_n
    new_arr = np.zeros(shape)
    for i, a in enumerate(arr.flatten()):
        new_arr += a * lookup[i]

    return new_arr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lookup = create_table((2, 2), (3, 3, 3))
    # Generate random 2 x 2 matrices.
    randos = (np.random.rand(2, 2) for _ in range(100000))
    results = map(lambda x: sum_expansion(x, lookup, (3, 3, 3)), randos)
    print(list(results))
```

To execute this code takes about 74 seconds on my machine. Are there any ways to reduce the time this code takes?

Comment: I suspect most of those 74 seconds are spent actually printing out the result.

Comment: Ahh geez lol. I think you're right (still going to investigate this a little bit more to make sure) Back to the drawing, there's a bottleneck in one of my other programs and I thought I had isolated it and made a MVE. Thanks!

Comment: I ran in `ipython` with `%run`and it took quite a while before printing.  The printing was relatively quick.  But apart from doing  something 100000 times,what is so slow?

Comment: @hpaulj: I need to run this on average 100000 per run, I am hoping to make it faster so that way each run isn't so slow.

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: @Divakar: there doesnt seem to be much (if any) improvement in the actual program (not this MVE) I'm trying to adapt a mixture of your solution and waterboy's. I have assignments I need to complete before I can really sink in. This proved to be a little more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I see. Well one observation is that the axes of reduction is of small length `4`, so I don't think you would see any noticeable improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such sum-reductions for multi-dimensional arrays, I think we could suggest [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) after reshaping `randos` to merge the last two axes into one, like so -

```
np.tensordot(np.array(randos).reshape(-1,4),lookup, axes=((-1),(0)))
```

Here's another one with reshaping the second array instead for using again with `np.tensordot` -

```
lookup_arr = np.asarray(lookup).reshape(2,2,3,3,3)
out = np.tensordot(randos,lookup_arr,axes=((-2,-1),(0,1)))
```

---

Runtime test -

```
In [69]: randos = [np.random.rand(2, 2) for _ in range(100)]

In [73]: lookup = create_table((2, 2), (3, 3, 3))

In [74]: lookup_arr = np.asarray(lookup).reshape(2,2,3,3,3)

In [75]: out1 = np.tensordot(np.array(randos).reshape(-1,4),lookup, axes=((-1),(0)))
    ...: out2 = np.tensordot(randos,lookup_arr,axes=((-2,-1),(0,1)))
    ...: 

In [76]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[76]: True

In [77]: %timeit np.tensordot(np.array(randos).reshape(-1,4),\
                                      lookup, axes=((-1),(0)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 37 µs per loop

In [78]: %timeit np.tensordot(randos,lookup_arr,axes=((-2,-1),(0,1)))
10000 loops, best of 3: 33.3 µs per loop

In [79]: %timeit np.asarray(lookup).reshape(2,2,3,3,3)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.18 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [20]: randos = [np.random.rand(2, 2) for _ in range(10)]

In [21]: timeit [sum_expansion(x,lookup,(3,3,3)) for x in randos]                                                       10000 loops, best of 3: 184 µs per loop
```

Off hand that time doesn't look bad.  Each call to `sum_expansion` takes 18 µs.

```
In [22]: timeit create_table((2,2),(3,3,3))                                                                             
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.1 µs per loop
```

It'll take more time to understand just what you are doing. I'm seeing a lot of Python iteration, and little `numpy` coding.

---

I get a 3x improvement using `einsum` to do the multiplication and sum:

```
def ein_expansion(arr, lookup, shape):                                                                                      
    return np.einsum('ij,ij...',arr, lookup) 

In [45]: L = np.array(lookup).reshape(2,2,3,3,3)

In [43]: timeit [ein_expansion(r, L,(3,3,3)) for r in randos]                                                           
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.3 µs per loop
```

We could get further improvements by operating on multiple `randos` arrays at once.

```
 In [59]: timeit np.einsum('oij,ij...->o...',np.array(randos),L)                                                         
 100000 loops, best of 3: 15.8 µs per loop   

 In [60]: np.einsum('oij,ij...->o...',np.array(randos),L).shape                                                           
 Out[60]: (10, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to look more into this. I am unfamiliar with the `einsum` and need a bit of time for this to sink in.

Comment: `(randos[0][:,:,None,None,None]*L).sum((0,1))` does the same thing, but isn't quite as fast.

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward using an einstein summation on properly reshaped arrays:

```
import numpy as np


def do_sum(x, mat_lst):
    a = np.array(x).flatten().reshape(1, -1)
    print('A shape: ', a.shape)
    b = np.stack(mat_lst)
    print('B shape: ', b.shape)
    return np.einsum('ij,jkl->kl', a, b)

A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B = [[[1,1],[1,1]],[[2,2],[2,2]],[[3,3],[3,3]],[[4,4],[4,4]]]

do_sum(A,B)
```

Outputs

```
A shape:  (1, 4)
B shape:  (4, 2, 2)

[[30 30]
 [30 30]]
```

---

**Edit - For generalized case**

This is generalized for a list of n-d input arrays. The only prerequisite is that the number of elements in `x` should equal the length of `mat_lst`.

```
def do_sum(x, mat_lst):
    a = np.array(x).flatten()
    b = np.stack(mat_lst)
    print("A shape: {}\nB shape: {}".format(a.shape, b.shape))
    return np.einsum('i,i...', a, b)

A = [[1,2],[3,4]]
B = [np.random.rand(2,2,2) for _ in range(4)]
do_sum(A,B)
```

(Note: There was no reason to reshape the flattened array, as I did previously, except to aid in understanding how einstein summations work (in my opinion, it's easier to visualize a (1x3) matrix than a (3,) matrix.) So, I've removed that here.)

The Einstein convention implies summation over indices that are repeated for each operand. In our generalized case of two matrices having the shape `a.shape = (n,)` and `b.shape = (n,...)`, we wish to sum over the first dimension of `a` and `b` only. We don't care about the depth of the other dimensions in `b`, or how many there may be, so we use `...` as a catch-all for the remainaing dimensions. The summation dimension(s) disappear from the output array, so the output array contains all other dimensions (i.e. `...`).

The subscript string passed to `einsum` captures all this information. On the input side of the string (everything to the left of `->`) we label the indices for each operand (i.e. the input matrices `a` and `b`), separated by commas. Indices to sum over are repeated (i.e. `i`). On the output side of the string (to the right of `->`) we indicate output indices. Our function doesn't need an output string because we want to output all the dimensions not included in the summation (I think).

Comment: Does this generalize to higher dimension matrices?

Comment: Yes -- see edits for the generalized case and some additional commentary.